# Pre shared keys (TLS-PSK) NGINX configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a very constrained device running on battery power that doesn't have the horsepower to do key exchange, so instead, we'd like to use PSK (pre-shared keys) to secure the channel.  I can't seem to find any information on how to configure this with NGINX.

I see that ssl_ciphers has PSK (which I've enabled) but where/how do I specify the shared keys between NGINX and the client?   Is this supported?

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer? I have the same problem, and the nginx "community" has been less than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, nginx does not support PSK ciphers. There is an attempt to add support though, some preliminary patches can be found here:

http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2017-September/010460.html

If you are interested in adding PSK support, please consider testing the patches and providing some feedback on them.

Comment: Anybody knows if this is still the case?

Answer (score 1):

You might use a stunnel for this. It supports TLS-PSK and is easy to set up!